# For wordpress, Is it better to develop live or locally?

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I am developing website by using word press. Now I am developing in live directly.

I recently get to know we can develop in local-host also. But I don't know which method is preferable and how to develop locally. If developing locally is good. Could you please suggest me the process too.

Comment: What do you mean by `developing` here? Are you just posting directly on live or actually developing new `themes` and `plugins`?

Comment: By using themes & plugins, I am developing website...

Comment: I will say if you are using ready made themes & plugins go live directly or if you need to customize them or need to create new one than better create whole site on local first & than go live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing your site in localhost. That's ok. But now problem arises here:

1. Uploading local site to live will be large time. Suppose that your site is about 150MB. Then it will take long time to upload.
2. Second problem is that all your featured image, media uploaded file or plugin may be reinstall again. Not sure, but may be.
3. You will have to change each path that you defined in localhost.

But if you are developing your site in live. Then it's very good.

1. Simply 4MB or 5MB wordpress files will not take long time.
2. There is no need to change any path

Since I am a wordpress developer so, I will prefer you to work on directly in live env.

Any help regarding this topic will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this really boils down to the characteristics of your Internet connection. If your connection is slow/unreliable/expensive, it would be better to develop locally first and then migrate to live when the dev work is completed. If the connection is not an issue, you can save yourself the trouble of migration by developing directly on live.

Another case in favor of live dev is if you need to show/share the work in progress with a client/others.

Finally, if/when you need to do local to live (or any other type of) migration, you can use this (excellent) plugin - works like a charm:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/